# Excel hierachy data for normal text

Tags: excel, hierarchy

I am quite new in this area, what I like to do is, For example:

Parents
  Child 1
  Child 2
  Child 3

I would like to collapse the child to parents in excel. Is it possible? I am using Excel 2010

[image] become
[image]

I found this while browsing. To be precise can Excel emulate Microsoft Project like this:
[image]

so I can hide all items under "Scope" in the image

Comment: any pointer on how to search this in internet will be much appreciated as well since english is not my native language

Comment: I don't need the time bar at the microsoft project. I am only looking to put some child under the parent subject which i can collapse or expand when needed

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible and its called Grouping & Outlining in Excel ,  its found on the Data tab

Here is a simple tutorial how to do it >> http://www.wikihow.com/Group-and-Outline-Excel-Data

Comment: the problem with this is it will hide the parents as well. while I want to collapse the child to parents.

Comment: just group the children!

Comment: but when i group the children, it will group the children to the row below and not above.